# Extract data from website and save the excel with every extraction

Tags: python

I have a Python script where I extract data from a website using multiple URLs saved in excel.
Currently, I have a script that saves the collected information in an excel file after looping the entire URLs available in excel.
Now the problem arises when the extraction interrupts due to network or any other way nothing is saved on the output file. As I have a script that provides output only after collecting all URLs info at once.

Now I need to update my script a little bit that now I want to open the URL from the input file, Collect data from the website one by one and immediately save the information to the output excel file. SO that if my code break in between at least my already collected data not lost.
Please find below my script which I'm using currently.
Please help me to do the changes.

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver.exe')

exampleFile = open("Desktop/Extraction.csv")
exampleReader = csv.reader(exampleFile)
exampleData = list(exampleReader)
final = []

records = []
for item in exampleData:
    final.append(item[0])
    
for url in final:
    driver.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'html.parser')
    results = soup.find_all('div',{'id':'dp'})

    for item in results:
        record = extract_record(item)
        if record:
            records.append(record)
          
driver.close()

df = pd.DataFrame(records)
df.columns = ['Link_url','item_name', 'Final_rate', 'Final_bullet','prod_desc','Image_link','Stock','Prod_spec1','Quantity_avail','Prod_spec2 ','Brand_info','Add_info','Delivered_by','BTG','Size_data','Design_data']
writer = ExcelWriter('E:/Data Scrap.xlsx')
df.to_excel(writer,'Sheet1',index=False)
writer.save()
```

Please let me know if you need further clarification.

Thanks

Comment: Mind sharing the URL?

Comment: I can't share the URL as this can't be accessed without a login. But it can be done by any URL that extracts any data from the website

Comment: For Example you can use these 2 urls

https://www.amazon.co.uk/SataanReaper-Jewellery-Valentine-Adjustable-Girlfriend/dp/B08YXPMYFJ/ref=sr_1_1?dchild=1&m=AKA2PIKJ8TDWP&marketplaceID=A1F83G8C2ARO7P&qid=1617621429&s=merchant-items&sr=1-1

https://www.amazon.co.uk/SataanReaper-Presents-Matels-Indian-Traditional/dp/B08W4L19TM/ref=sr_1_2?dchild=1&m=AKA2PIKJ8TDWP&marketplaceID=A1F83G8C2ARO7P&qid=1617621429&s=merchant-items&sr=1-2

Answer (score 0):

The improvements needed are a bit broad so I'll summarise:

1. [`df.to_excel()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_excel.html) and `df.to_csv()` will overwrite the target file each time it's written, so it can only be written to once or you need to keep overwriting the file with more data. Not efficient but works.
2. What you could do instead is keep writing out to `csv` using [`csvwriter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.writer) in append mode, and do this inside the loop. So if it breaks for any reason, the last record will still be written.

   ```py
   import csv
   with open('E:/Data Scrap.csv', 'a', newline='') as csvfile:
       datawriter = csv.writer(csvfile)
       for url in final:
           driver.get(url)
           soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'html.parser')
           results = soup.find_all('div',{'id':'dp'})

           for item in results:
               record = extract_record(item)
               if record:
                   # records.append(record)  # not needed
                   datawriter.writerow(record)  # do this instead
   ```
3. Alternatively, you could put your entire `for url in final:` inside a `try...except` block so that as soon as it errors out, it continues with `driver.close()` and `df = pd.DataFrame(records)`, etc.

   ```py
   try:
       for url in final:
           driver.get(url)
           ...    
           for item in results:
               record = extract_record(item)
               if record:
                   records.append(record)
   except:  # bad to have an empty exception, put the one's which actually occur              
       driver.close()

   df = pd.DataFrame(records,
                     columns = ['Link_url', 'item_name', 'Final_rate', ...
                                'BTG', 'Size_data', 'Design_data']
   )
   ...  # remaining code
   ```
4. If you think an error will only occur for some iterations but not necessarily for all the rest, then put the `try...except` block inside the for-loop, each iteration has it's own error handling, so that it will continue till the end. Note that it has a minor performance impact but with a network/IO call like `driver.get()`, you won't notice it.

   ```py
   for url in final:
       try:
           driver.get(url)
           ...
           for item in results:
               record = extract_record(item)
               if record:
                   records.append(record)
       except:  # again, bad
           pass  # at least print the error traceback so you know
           # will then continue when the next iteration of the for-loop

   driver.close()
   df = pd.DataFrame(records)
   ...  # remaining code
   ```
5. Instead of `records` as a list you're appending to, you could keep [appending to a dataframe](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.append.html) and use option 3 or 4 above. And then write it to excel outside the loop.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your support now the code runs perfectly fine